# How to prevent centered text in input button be moved when dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input button with a centered text. Text length is changing dynamically with a js (dots animation), that causes text moving inside the button.
Strict aligning with padding doesn't suit because the text in the button will be used in different languages and will have different lenghts. Need some versatile solution. The main text should be centered and the dots should be aligned left to the end of the main text.

```
var dots = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#payDots').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setInterval(type, 600);
  })

});

function type() {
  var dot = '.';
  if(dots < 3) {
    $('#payDots').val('processing' + dot.repeat(dots));
    dots++;
  }
  else {
    $('#payDots').val('processing');
    dots = 0;
  }
}
```

---

```
<input id="payDots" type="button" value="Pay" class="button">
```

---

```
.button{
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v8g4rfsw/1/    (button should be pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest as this is a value and extra elements can't be inserted, would be to just use leading spaces to make the text appear as it's always centered.

This uses the plugin I wrote for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248405/adding-some-javascript-variable-into-inputs-value-attribute/45248435#45248435)

```js
$.fn.dots = function(time, dots) {
  return this.each(function(i,el) {
    clearInterval( $(el).data('dots') );
    
    if ( time !== 0 ) {
      var d = 0;
      $(el).data('dots', setInterval(function() {
        $(el).val(function(_,v) {
          if (d < dots) {
            d++;
            return ' ' + v + '.';
          } else {
            d = 0;
            return v.substring(dots, v.length - dots)
          }
        })
      }, time));
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#payDots').on('click', function() {
    $(this).val('Proccessing').prop('disabled',true).dots(600, 3);
  });
});
```

```css
.button{
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="payDots" type="button" value="Pay" class="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find updated code below 
[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v8g4rfsw/1/)

HTML Code

```
<button id="payDots">
<span>Pay</span>
</button>
```

JS Code

```
var dots = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#payDots').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setInterval(type, 600);
  })

});

function type() {
$('button').css('padding-left','100px','important');
  var dot = '.';
  if(dots < 3) {
    $('#payDots').text('processing' + dot.repeat(dots));

    dots++;
  }
  else {
    $('#payDots').text('processing');
    dots = 0;
  }
}
```

CSS Code

```
button{
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:130px;
}
```